# Upload apk using carrierwave and store both apk and extracted icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apk, carrierwave

I have a App model which has_many Versions
The versions model has an `apk` and an `icon` field (among others).

I currently have a form that allows users to upload an .apk file using carrierwave (`class VersionUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base`).

Once the apk file is uploaded I've used the [ruby_apk](https://github.com/SecureBrain/ruby_apk) gem to extract the icon (from within `versions_uploader.rb`).

For the icon, the ruby_apk gem returns an array of hashes in the following format

`{ "res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" => "\x89PNG\x0D\x0A...", ... }`

I would like to save the icon to disk and have it accessible the same way I would the apk file (By this i mean be able to call things like version.icon.identifier on it)

I've been stuck on this for a while now. Any help regarding how it should be done or what approach would be best would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working. Taavo's answer set me in the right direction but it didn't work as expected.

The main problem was that StringIO.new(icon_data) kept giving me a `no implicit conversion of nil into string` error. After quite some digging I found that I needed to add `original_filename` as an attribute to StringIO, but it has long since stopped accepting this without monkey patching the class. I found the solution to this problem from the Carrierwave wiki psge: [How to: Upload from a string in Rails 3](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Upload-from-a-string-in-Rails-3).

This now let me save the icon to the file-system but mysteriously, was not populating the Version.icon field with the reference (Version.apk was populated without any problems).

In the end, to get it working I had to get rid of the `before_Save :assign_icon` callback and moved my code into the ApkUploader file.

My code looks something like this:

1) Created a new initializer that inherits from StringIO

#### config/initializers/stringiohax.rb

```
class AppSpecificStringIO < StringIO
  attr_accessor :filepath

  def initialize(*args)
    super(*args[1..-1])
    @filepath = args[0]
  end

  def original_filename
    File.basename(filepath)
  end
end
```

2) Mount Uploaders

#### app/models/version.rb

```
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :apk, ApkUploader
  mount_uploader :icon, IconUploader
```

3) Extract data from APK and save icon attribute

#### app/models/version.rb

```
class ApkUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Sprockets::Rails::Helper
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  require 'ruby_apk'

  ..
  ...

  process :extract_apk_info

  def store_dir
    app = App.find(model.app_id)
    studio_name = Studio.find(app.studio_id).slug
    "uploads/#{studio_name}/#{app.id}/version_#{model.version_code}"
  end

  def extract_apk_info
    apk = Android::Apk.new(model.apk.path.to_s)
    manifest  = apk.manifest
    icons     = apk.icon

    icon_name = icons.keys.last
    icon_data = icons.values.last

    model.package_name = manifest.package_name
    model.version_code = manifest.version_code
    model.version_name = manifest.version_name
    model.min_sdk_ver  = manifest.min_sdk_ver
    model.icon         = AppSpecificStringIO.new(icon_name, icon_data)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This gets a lot easier if you use two different uploaders, and set the icon data from the model layer. Model code could look something like this:

```
mount_uploader :apk, ApkUploader
mount_uploader :icon, IconUploader
before_save :assign_icon

def assign_icon
  if apk_changed?
    icon_data = Android::Apk.new(apk.path).icons.values.first
    self.icon = StringIO.new(icon_data)
  end
end
```

Note that `before_save` has to come after `mount_uploader :apk`, because `mount_uploader` creates [its own callbacks](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb#L29) on the `before_save` event, and you want to fire after them.